# Generating random primary key during bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I am trying to read some data from .csv and add the to a table with a randomly generated primary key.

So I created a database, added a table and if I insert data 1 by 1 the everything is fine but I want to add the data in bulk and I'm not sure if the primary key would be automatically generated or not.

I created a view and the added everything to the view except the Id column and then called the bulk insert on the view.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
     PersonID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
     FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     StreetAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     City VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     State_prov VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     Zip VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     phoneNumber VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     SSN VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
)

CREATE VIEW viewPerson
AS
    SELECT everything other than personID
    FROM Person

BULK INSERT viewPerson
FROM 'Data1.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

Sample data:

```
Olivia,Abbas,7823 West Charles Lan,Bothell,WA,98012,956) 692-3392,770-78-9562
Isla,Abbey,9534 East Bank Ave,Bothell,WA,98012,(413) 296-8853,770-78-9563
Amara,Abbott,9535 East Bank Ave,Bothell,WA,98012,(788) 281-2027,770-78-9564
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 11, column 7 (SSN).
>
> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 12, column 7 (SSN).
>
> Msg 4865, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>   Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of errors (10) was exceeded.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 62
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

And there is nothing in the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksjrh.png)

Comment: Note the row numbers in the error messages (11 and 12). Check those records in the source file. It may be the SSN is too long in those records or a other issues, like extra commas, etc.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem relevant to your actual question?

Comment: Does the error occur when you try to import your sample data?

Comment: yes, I check the data there is no problem or mistake. I even added the line that it says there is an error by itself and it worked

Comment: please show row 10 to 12 of the source file

Comment: I added an image of the first 30 rows of data

Comment: As a side note, you really should reconsider the choice of `newID()` as the source of your primary key - especially since in SQL Server, the primary key is also the clustered index of the table by default (unless specified otherwise). This usually leads to high page fragmentation and therefor poor performance.

Comment: I suggest you inspect the CSV file in a text editor rather than in excel. Excel can hide or exacerbate data issues.

Comment: Even looking at the csv, you will notice that the last column is extended by excel, suggesting there might be a lot of spaces at the end of the column. As @Nick.McDermaid suggests, use a text editor, preferable showing hidden characters, and yuo will probably work it out.

Comment: Yes - assuming SSN is the last column (we don't know - your sample doesn't tell us), it's quite possible that there's a bunch of spaces that is truncating it.